# CSS Transitions not working (partly) on Safari using styled-component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, css-transitions, styled-components

I have applied css transitions all over my app and it's working flawlessly on firefox and chrome but the problem it is not working all the time on Safari for some reason sometimes the animation will choke sometimes it will partly transition sometimes works but I am not sure why

I am using explicit transition declarations not using `all` always like this `transition: color 1s linear` for example

I tried `-webkit-transition` even though Styled-components automatically do this but no luck too

I tried clearing cache and reload nothing changed

I am using NextJS with styled-components

transitions that are triggered on `hover` all working normally

any suggestions ?

one of the glitching components

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { colors } from "../styles/SharedStyles";

const DarkModeToggle = styled.div`
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 1.25rem;
  right: 1.25rem;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  cursor: pointer;
  clip-path: circle();
  background-image: ${({ theme }) =>
    theme.body !== colors.white
      ? `url("/images/misc/dark-logo.svg")`
      : `url("/images/misc/light-logo.svg")`};
  background-color: ${({ theme }) =>
    theme.body !== colors.white ? colors.gray[700] : colors.secondary};
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: ${(props) => (props.theme.body !== colors.white ? `60%` : `70%`)};
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 98;
`;

export default DarkModeToggle;
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what it's doing and try to reproduce it?

Comment: added a styled-component that is glitching to question